# How do I stop scrolling on one panel as another finishes scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I have two adjacent panels (aside and article) and I want the aside (with content with less height than the viewport) to stop scrolling until the article (with content with greater height than the viewport) has finished scrolling.

Here's my CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.container {    /*  containing my aside and article  */
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

aside, article {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This works to handle the scrolling -- however, I want the entire screen to stop until the article has concluded scrolling, even if I am scrolling while my cursor is over the aside panel.

This website performs the behavior I'm after: https://www.technologyreview.com/

Any ideas for a pure CSS solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the rest of your markup so we have a demo? If I understand correctly, a CSS solution might be to use `position: sticky` but browser support isn't very good https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmwZLg you might also look at bootstrap's affix. The example on technologyreview.com is traditionally done with javascript

Comment: That's what I figured -- I'd need to resort to Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, Michael!

Comment: No sweat. Does `position: sticky` work like you were expecting? If so I can leave it as an answer, since it's a way to do it in CSS, but not really a production solution since the browser support sucks.